# Change colour of rest of page

Tags: html, css

I have an issue on a site I'm building.

Not all of the pages are long enough to fill the whole browser, leaving white at the bottom. You can see in the image below the issue.

[image]

You can see there is white space below the webpage.

Effectively I want to extend the footer to fill the remainder of the page.

Note that setting the color of HTML works in only FireFox.

Below is my relevant CSS code

http://hastebin.com/itaniparuz.css

Additionally, below is the HTML for the page used in my example image:

http://hastebin.com/nedipipibi.xml

The code above is slightly messy as I had to replace a few includes with the code they contain however I think its clear to see how the page is coded.

Any suggestions as to the best way to do this?

---

**Answer:** I fixed this by adding

```
min-height: 100vh;
background-color: #3D3D3D;
```

To the body div and then readjusting some of the HTML.

Comment: We can help if you post your code you are working with.

Comment: Thanks, however I have already received the answer. Could I ask why this was down voted to I could fix it to get it up voted again?

Comment: I am not sure, I did not downvote this. Maybe because you did not share the code you were working on.

Comment: Okay, thank-you I will attach the code I am using now so as to help future users who have a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following CSS:

```
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

This will make your page's height at least equal to the viewport's height.

**Update:** As reminded by panther in the comments, check [this](http://caniuse.com/#search=vh) for browser compatibility.

**Update 2:** This will only do what you expect if the footer is stuck to the bottom, of course. See [Keith Tomas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30442066/3334049) for the CSS that does sticks the footer to the bottom of the page.

Comment: You should put a link to table of browser's support. http://caniuse.com/#search=vh, support is just partial in these days.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue, in the end I set the <div id='body'> to a min height of 100vh and then set the colour of it to the colour I wanted to fill the rest page with as the background colour of the div.

Answer (score 0):

If the footer background color is darkgrey, set this color to `body`. White background will be set to `#content` part. See the trick with left/right padding and negative margin.

```
<style>
    body {margin: 0; background: #333;}
    #outer {overflow: hidden;}
    #wrapper {width: 980px; margin: 0 auto;}
    #content {margin: 0 -1000px; padding: 20px 1000px; background: white;}
    #footer {color: #fff; padding: 20px 0;}
</style>

<div id="outer">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content">content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content</div>
        <div id="footer">footer</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6e84awv4/

Answer (score 0):

You could also move the footer down to the bottom with something like this:

```
#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```